# Проблемы с работой ViewPageAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Не могу понять, как мне создавать TextView и остальное для каждой вкладки отдельно. Я новичек, пожалуйста обьясните как вы это делаете :D

Вот код

```
    package com.example.hondle.biling.activity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.hondle.biling.R;
import com.example.hondle.biling.SimpleRecyclerAdapter;
import com.example.hondle.biling.TabsHeaderActivity;
import com.example.hondle.biling.VersionModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TabAnimationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:

                        showToast("One");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        showToast("Two");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        showToast("Three");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_material_light)), "Инфо");
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.ripple_material_light)), "Офисы");
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_material_dark)), "Карта");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tab_switch, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_switch:
                Intent intent = new Intent(TabAnimationActivity.this, TabsHeaderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    public static class DummyFragment extends Fragment {
        int color;
        SimpleRecyclerAdapter adapter;

        public DummyFragment() {
        }

        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public DummyFragment(int color) {
            this.color = color;
        }



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment, container, false);

            final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_bg);
            frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_scrollableview);

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < VersionModel.data.length; i++) {
                list.add(VersionModel.data[i]);
            }

            adapter = new SimpleRecyclerAdapter(list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

UPD: Кому не ясно что я хочу. У меня есть 3 вкладки и я не могу понять как взаимодействовать с ViewPageAdapter , что бы для каждой вкладки отдельно создавать кнопки,текст и остальное. Весь код привел, для большего понимая. Конструкция вроде бы обычная, для тех кто разбирается, тот поймет.

Comment: Ваша задача и проблема в её решении совершенно не ясна. И зачем нам весь ваш код? Покажите только проблемный участок.

Comment: Я обновил шапку.

Comment: Всё ещё не ясна проблема... Вы не знаете как разные фрагменты отображить на разных страницах?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в этом методе:

```
   private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_material_light)), "Инфо");
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.ripple_material_light)), "Офисы");
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_material_dark)), "Карта");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Если вы хотите на каждой странице отображать разные элементы -  вам нужны разные фрагменты.

Либо в адаптере переопредилить метод:

```
  @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        DummyFragment fragment = DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_material_dark)), "Карта");

        //Тут можно произвести манипуляции с вашим фрагментом

        return fragment;
    }
```